# Не работает php авторизация

Tags: php

Есть форма авторизации.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
      <div class="textbox">
          <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин" >
      </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
  </div>

  <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти">
  </div>
</form>
```

Далее PHP поверка

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $user = $_POST['login'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $user1 = trim($user);
  $user2 = stripslashes($user1);
  $user3 = strip_tags($user2);
  $user = htmlspecialchars($user3);

  $password1 = trim($password);
  $password2 = stripslashes($password1);
  $password3 = strip_tags($password2);
  $password = htmlspecialchars($password3);

  if (strlen($user) < 3) {
    echo "<script>alert('Короткий логин');</script>";
  }

  if (strlen($password) < 5) {
    echo "<script>alert('Короткий пароль');</script>";
  }

  $auth = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$user' AND `password` = '$password'");
  $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($auth);
  if (count($result) == 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('Пользователь не найден');</script>";
  }
}
 ?>
```

Для того, чтобы сделать куки я после переменной `if count` поставил `else`.

```
if (count($result) == 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('Пользователь не найден');</script>";
  } else {
    setcookie('user', $user['login'], time() + 3600 * 24 * 7, "/");
  }
```

Но была ошибка, тогда я переместил строчку setcookie в самое начало файла. При правильных данных ошибки не было, но куки не отображалось.

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE['user'] == '') {
  echo "Нет";
} else {
  echo "Есть";
}
 ?>
```

В тоже время поместив в начало `print_r($_COOKIE);` вывелась строка

```
Array
(
    [PHPSESSID] => цифры
)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Comment: А откуда у вас возьмется `$user['login']`? насколько я помню, несколько строчек назад было так: `$user = htmlspecialchars($user3);`, была строка а стала массивом?

Comment: $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($auth);

Comment: ну, присвоили в `$result`, а `$user['login']` откуда хоть появился?

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена.